# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ship_img'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a game in pygame, but I can't change the color of the sprite in the options menu. I'm trying to shove self.ship_img into a var that will be accessible from the options menu. English is not my main language, so I apologize if something is unclear.This is my first python project, so I'll learning the language in the process

```
YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_yellow.png"))
PURPLE_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_purple.png"))
GREEN1_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_green.png"))
```

```
class Ship:
    COOLDOWN = 30

    def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.laser_img = None
        self.lasers = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0
```

```
class Player(Ship):
    def __init__(self, x, y, ship_img, health=100 ):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.ship_img = ship_img
        self.laser_img = YELLOW_LASER
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
        self.max_health = health
```

```
def options():
    ship_img = None
    while run:
        if button_green.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                ship_img = GREEN1_SPACE_SHIP
        if button_purple.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                ship_img = PURPLE_SPACE_SHIP
        if button_yellow.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                ship_img = YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP
    return ship_img
```

Perhaps the solution is very easy, but I can not get to it. Thanks for help

Comment: @Rabbid76 I couldn't solve the problem, so I skipped this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop in the function `options` is an endless loop. Remove the loop, but call `options` in the application loop:

```py
def options():
    ship_img = None
    if click:
        if button_green.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            ship_img = GREEN1_SPACE_SHIP
        if button_purple.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            ship_img = PURPLE_SPACE_SHIP
        if button_yellow.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            ship_img = YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP
    return ship_img
```

---

To change the image of an existing object, add a `change_image` method to the `Player` class:

```py
class Player(Ship):
    # [...]

    def change_image(self, ship_img):
        self.ship_img = ship_img
```

Invoke the method when you click the button:

```py
def options(ship):
    if click:
        if button_green.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            ship.change_image(GREEN1_SPACE_SHIP)
        if button_purple.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            ship.change_image(PURPLE_SPACE_SHIP)
        if button_yellow.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            ship.change_image(YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP)
```